# Uninstall fails because program is running. How do I make Inno Setup check for running process prior to attempting delete?

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup fails to remove components during uninstall cause my program is still running and the executable cannot be deleted. How do I have it check to see if it is running before allowing uninstall to proceed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check these

[Inno Setup: Detect instances running in any user session with AppMutex](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?mutexsessions)

[Inno Setup: Is application running?](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Application_considerations#Application_is_running)

[Inno Setup: Detect if an application is running](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Detect_if_an_application_is_running)

There are several ways. If your program defines a mutex use

```
[Setup]
AppMutex=MyMutexName
```

or for a specified mutex in the `Code` section

```
function CheckForMutexes (Mutexes: String): Boolean;
```

You could also use

```
function FindWindowByClassName (const ClassName: String): Longint;
```

to get the window handle by class name and send it messages.

Or get it by the name

```
function FindWindowByWindowName (const WindowName: String): Longint;
```

Or you use one of several DLL files for this specific use case

- [PSVince](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=PSVince)
- [FindProcDLL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FindProcDLL_plug-in)

Or do it yourself after reading

[How To Terminate an Application "Cleanly" in Win32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893/en-us)

[How To Enumerate Applications Using Win32 APIs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175030/de) (this one links to the german version as for some reason I can't find the english version of KB175030

or try the google translated version of the KB175030-DE

[KB175030 DE -> EN](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fkb%2F175030%2Fde&sl=de&tl=en&history_state0=&swap=1)

Comment: Awesome answer. Very thorough; thank you! The global mutex option took 5 minutes to get it right! Nothing better than that.

Comment: The latest English version of KB 175030 that I could find on the Wayback Machine is from February 2007:  http://web.archive.org/web/20070216103757/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175030.

Comment: A couple more options for checking for a running app at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30852146/550712.

Answer (score 28):

We used an other way than described above. Because this is an uninstallation we can kill the application and unistall it.
The simpliest way, when u can't use AppMutex: (related to [Really killing a process in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988/really-killing-a-process-in-windows))

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""taskkill /im <precessname>.exe /f /t"
```

Hope somebody will help this. I searched a long time for this.

Comment: Does the `taskkill` kill more than one running instance of the same process ?

Comment: Thanks! Yup, it kills all the instances unless you run the setup with lower privileges than the process is elevated. [+1ed anyway :)]

Comment: Seems to kill the process, but the uninstaller still sees the files as locked and does not remove them.

Answer (score 13):

Try this solution!  I had issues with other solutions closing the app, but Inno Setup still thought the installed files were locked.

Remember to define your constants:

```
#define MyAppName "AppName"
#define MyAppExeName "AppName.exe"

[Code]
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
  var ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('open','taskkill.exe','/f /im {#MyAppExeName}','',SW_HIDE,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
  ShellExec('open','tskill.exe',' {#MyAppName}','',SW_HIDE,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
  result := True;
end;
```

Major props to the [original source of this solution](http://dallascao.com/en/end-a-process-with-inno-setup/).

Comment: This is great, one thing that I changed was to use a different procedure instead of "function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;" due to the fact that this function will kill the app even if the user cancels the uninstall process whereas "procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm;" will run only if he confirms to uninstall.

Comment: Great solution, worked really well in my case. Thx!

Answer (score 11):

Use the [`AppMutex` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex) to prevent the uninstaller from proceeding, when an application is running.

```
[Setup]
AppMutex=MyProgMutex
```

The application has to create the mutex specified by the directive. See the linked `AppMutex` directive documentation for examples.

---

If you want to have the uninstaller kill the application, when it is still running, use this code instead:

```pascal
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if CheckForMutexes('MyProgMutex') and
     (MsgBox('Application is running, do you want to close it?',
             mbConfirmation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDOK) then
  begin
    Exec('taskkill.exe', '/f /im MyProg.exe', '', SW_HIDE, 
         ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

As with the `AppMutex` directive above, the application has to create the mutex specified in the [`CheckForMutexes`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_checkformutexes) call.

---

Note that for installer, you do not have to code this. The installer has restart manager built-in.
See [Kill process before (re)install using "taskkill /f /im" in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33776405/850848#33777149).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps add this property

CloseApplications=yes
it will look at all the [Files] and [InstallDelete] elements and work using windows restart manager

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplications