# Inno setup, check for process during a .exe is running and kill it

Tags: inno-setup

I need some help with inno setup. If it is possible, I would like to know how to:

Check if a process appears during the time an .exe file is running (the .exe is called from inno installation) and if the process appears kill it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Inno-setup doesn't really have much to do with your question.  It doesn't matter if the monitoring program is started from inno-setup or some other way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576792/uninstall-fails-because-program-is-running-how-do-i-make-inno-setup-check-for-ru

Answer (score 0):

Make a DLL and link to it from your script. In the DLL, use the windows API to accomplish what you need. For example:

```
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent( CTRL_C_EVENT, dwProcessId)
```

will send a `control-C` to a console application. OR:

```
TerminateProcess( ProcessHandle, 1);
```

will terminate the referenced process. Check MSDN for details.

Answer (score 0):

Close running process you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014649/2952483
Then just do it on timer (TTimer if you use chinease extended version of inno setup, or callback functions if you use standart (like here [Inno setup: Display Images using timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522255/inno-setup-display-images-using-timer)))

Answer (score 0):

you can execute a cmd with Exec() in inno setup, and check ResultCode value.eg:

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C tasklist | findstr "test.exe"', '',         SW_SHOWNORMAL,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

if ResultCode is not 0,execute a cmd again will kill the test.exe process.

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C taskkill /IM test.exe', '',         SW_SHOWNORMAL,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```