# Inno Setup Kill a running process

Tags: installation, inno-setup, kill

I have already implemented a way to find whether a process ("iexplore.exe") is running, I now need to find a way to close it (terminate the process) from Inno Setup.

```pascal
strProg := 'iexplore.exe';
winHwnd := FindWindowByWindowName(strProg);
MsgBox('winHwnd: ' + inttostr(winHwnd),  mbInformation, MB_OK );
if winHwnd <> 0 then
  retVal:=postmessage(winHwnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
```

The message box in the example above will always return 0 therefore no handle is ever gotten.
(the `WM_CLOSE` constant in the example is properly initialized)
I need another way of doing this, and hopefully one that does not involve writing a C++ DLL that does this (I am not proficient in C++, I might be able to write a DLL in C#, however I don't know whether Inno Setup will interop with that).

This C# DLL would get the process list, iterate thru the names of processes, find a match (=="iexplorer") and then kill the processes with that name...however I am still hoping to find an easier solution so that I wouldnt have to interop it with Pascal script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just found this:http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;en-us;q178893

Answer (score 7):

Version with use of `Win32_Process`, you call the procedure with i.e. 'notepad.exe':

```pascal
const wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;

procedure CloseApp(AppName: String);
var
  WbemLocator : Variant;
  WMIService   : Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
  WbemObject   : Variant;
begin;
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WMIService := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');
  WbemObjectSet := WMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where Name="' + AppName + '"');
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    WbemObject := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(0);
    if not VarIsNull(WbemObject) then
    begin
      WbemObject.Terminate();
      WbemObject := Unassigned;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes several assumptions that are wrong, and you should address them all:

- It's a bad idea to close any program without asking the user first. Consider the case of Internet Explorer, the user may have some web pages open with forms partially filled in - if you close them unconditionally you may actively piss off the user because they lost work.
  **What you should do instead:** Check whether any program is open that interferes with the normal progress of your installation, and if one is found alert the user that they need to close it. Ask them in a loop whether to cancel or to repeat the check, and do not continue unless all interfering programs are closed.
- If you really need to send a `WM_CLOSE` message to a window, then the support function `FindWindowByWindowName()` won't work. Why would the *window name* of an Internet Explorer window be "iexplore.exe"? It will be the title of the open web page, so you won't know beforehand what it is.
  **What you should do instead:** Use the much more appropriate `FindWindowByClassName()` function. With a tool like Spy++ or UI Spy or similar you can find out what the class name of a program window is. For Internet Explorer on my system it is "IEFrame", but can you really rely on that? Again, better give the user control over things, and repeat the running process check until all interfering programs have been closed.
- Closing a single window with the matching window or class name may not be enough. A single Windows process may have more than one window open, and there may be several instances of the same executable running, each with one or more windows open.
  **What you should do instead:** Execute your checking (and closing) code in a loop until everything is ready to proceed.
- But even then you should be prepared for things to go wrong - Windows is a multitasking system, and new processes may be spawned or windows be opened at any time. If AutoPlay is enabled then inserting a CD or USB stick could open an Internet Explorer window right when you think that you have closed them all.

Comment: Point 1) good point, I am aware of this and my 1st solution was using an inno setup addon that prompts the user to close the program(s) before proceeding - the management rejected this solution because the want to minimize interference with the user. Our users can barely find where the windows start button is, let alone READ a prompt and make a right choice. The loop you mentioned in our case would cause angry phone calls that the computer is frozen, although its the most logical solution to us who are tech savvy...

Comment: Point 2) Yes, all of these methods are unreliable, thats why I was thinking about killing a process, not a window, yet I do not know how to achieve this (kill process) via Inno, I will try with FindWindowByClassName now that I realize whats wrong with WindowName

Comment: Point 3) Again my preferred solution would be killing the processes named iexplore.exe

Comment: Point 4) Yeah, million of potential fail points...seems to me that for every 1 line of code I have to write 5 lines of error handling code and about 12 lines of anti-user-fault code...users seem to have an uncanny ability to immidiately find a way to crash the program, and after they have done it, they cant explain HOW they did it, until it happens again :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and wrote a short C++ program to kill certain processes that might be in a hung state and thus unable to respond to messages telling them to die.  I only did this with applications that were part of my product, not system applications.

You could do the same thing in Pascal script if you want to suffer the pain of getting the calling parameters correct.  Here is an outline of what I did:

Get the location of CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES.  Inno setup can do this with its {pf} or {pf32} constants. Or call the Windows api SHGetSpecialFolderLocation function.

Set a string equal to the path to the process you want to kill, for example
String target = pf + "Mycompany/MyAppFolder/myHelperApp.exe"

Call the Windows api function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, which returns a list of running processes.

Look through this returned list for your target using the Windows api's OpenProcess and GetModuleFleNameEx.

When you find the target call the Windows api TerminateProcess on the target process handle.

Answer (score 1):

```pascal
const 
  WM_QUIT = 18;

function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
var
  winHwnd: longint;
  retVal : boolean;
  strProg: string;
begin
  Result := true;
  strProg := 'Readme.txt - Notepad';
  winHwnd := FindWindowByWindowName(strProg);
  MsgBox('winHwnd: ' + inttostr(winHwnd),  mbInformation, MB_OK );
  if winHwnd<>0 then begin                    { no module found or ignored pressed}
    MsgBox('ravi:' #13#13 'Bye bye!', mbInformation, MB_OK); 
    abort();                                      { continue setup  }
  end;
end;
```

It works fine..

Using that code, I'm able to trace exit application which is running...