# WbemObject.Terminate failure reason

Tags: wmi, inno-setup

As for now, I'm improving logging in my Inno Setup installer, so if consumer will get some sort of error, I can easily see, what went wrong.

As one of installation actions, I kill application process, if it is running, to overwrite files gracefully. To kill application, I use approach, which is described in question [Inno Setup Kill a running process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545077/850848) - getting `WbemObject` and calling `WbemObject.Terminate`.

As for now, I want to track, if `Terminate` was successful. From my testing, I've found out, that it actually returns boolean, indicating, whether application was terminated successfully. But if it fails, it simply returns "false". And I want to know more detailed reason.

So, is there way to get actual failure reason for `WbemObject.Terminate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have, is not `WbemObject`, it's [`Win32_Process` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process).

The [`Win32_Process.Terminate` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/terminate-method-in-class-win32-process) does return `uint32` (`Cardinal` in Pascal), not `Boolean`:

> Returns a value of 0 (zero) if the process was successfully terminated, and any other number to indicate an error. For additional error codes, see [WMI Error Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants) or [WbemErrorEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemdisp/ne-wbemdisp-wbemerrorenum). For general **HRESULT** values, see [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes).
>
> **Successful completion** (0)
> **Access denied** (2)
> **Insufficient privilege** (3)
> **Unknown failure** (8)
> **Path not found** (9)
> **Invalid parameter** (21)
> **Other** (22–4294967295)