# How do you close then restart explorer.exe in Inno Setup uninstall using the Restart Manager?

Tags: inno-setup, windows-restart-manager

Does anyone know of a sample or can provide a sample of how to use the Restart Manager built-in to Windows to close explorer.exe at the beginning of the uninstall process of Inno Setup then restarting it just after files removed ?  I have some shell items that even after unregistered is still allocated and can't be removed until explorer.exe is closed.

TIA!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it:

```pascal
{ Example how to use RestartManager and Offer Option to Delete App Data during Uninstall of Inno Setup }
{ Combined multiple open source ISS code found with some custom changes }
{ This could probably be cleaned up a bit, my goal was to get something to work. }
{ I also stripped it down a bit as I had multiple applications and data so hope }
{ everything removed without an issue, but I'm sure you can figure it out if so }

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

{ Copies a NULL-terminated array of characters to a string. }
function ArrayToString(Chars:array of Char):String;
var
    Len,i:Longint;
begin
    Len:=GetArrayLength(Chars);
    SetLength(Result,Len);
    i:=0;
    while (i<Len) and (Chars[i]<>#0) do begin
        Result[i+1]:=Chars[i];
        i:=i+1;
    end;
    SetLength(Result,i);
end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

type
    LONG      = Longint;
    ULONG     = Cardinal;
    IdList=array of DWORD;
    ProcessEntry=record
        ID:DWORD;
        Name:String;
        Restartable,ToTerminate:Boolean;
    end;
    ProcessList=array of ProcessEntry;

{
    Code for Windows Vista and above
}

const
    { Return codes. }
    ERROR_SUCCESS        = 0;
    ERROR_MORE_DATA      = 234;
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

    CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY  = 32;
    CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME = 255;
    CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME = 63;

    RmUnknownApp  = 0;    { The application cannot be classified as any other type. An application of this type can only be shut down by a forced shutdown. }
    RmMainWindow  = 1;    { A Windows application run as a stand-alone process that displays a top-level window. }
    RmOtherWindow = 2;    { A Windows application that does not run as a stand-alone process and does not display a top-level window. }
    RmService     = 3;    { The application is a Windows service. }
    RmExplorer    = 4;    { The application is Windows Explorer. }
    RmConsole     = 5;    { The application is a stand-alone console application. }
    RmCritical    = 1000; { A system restart is required to complete the installation because a process cannot be shut down. }

    RmStatusUnknown        = $0000;
    RmStatusRunning        = $0001;
    RmStatusStopped        = $0002;
    RmStatusStoppedOther   = $0004;
    RmStatusRestarted      = $0008;
    RmStatusErrorOnStop    = $0010;
    RmStatusErrorOnRestart = $0020;
    RmStatusShutdownMasked = $0040;
    RmStatusRestartMasked  = $0080;

    RmForceShutdown          = $0001;
    RmShutdownOnlyRegistered = $0010;

type
    SessionKey=array[1..CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY+1] of Char;

    FILETIME=record
        dwLowDateTime,dwHighDateTime:DWORD;
    end;
    RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS=record
        dwProcessId:DWORD;
        ProcessStartTime:FILETIME;
    end;
    RM_APP_TYPE=DWORD;
    RM_PROCESS_INFO=record
        Process:RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS;
        strAppName:array[1..CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME+1] of Char;
        strServiceShortName:array[1..CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME+1] of Char;
        ApplicationType:RM_APP_TYPE;
        AppStatus:ULONG;
        TSSessionId:DWORD;
        bRestartable:BOOL;
    end;
    RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK=DWORD;

function RmStartSession(var pSessionHandle:DWORD;dwSessionFlags:DWORD;strSessionKey:SessionKey):DWORD;
external 'RmStartSession@Rstrtmgr.dll stdcall delayload';

function RmEndSession(dwSessionHandle:DWORD):DWORD;
external 'RmEndSession@Rstrtmgr.dll stdcall delayload';

function RmRegisterResources(dwSessionHandle:DWORD;hFiles:UINT;rgsFilenames:TArrayOfString;nApplications:UINT;rgApplications:array of RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS;nServices:UINT;rgsServiceNames:TArrayOfString):DWORD;
external 'RmRegisterResources@Rstrtmgr.dll stdcall delayload';

function RmGetList(dwSessionHandle:DWORD;var pnProcInfoNeeded,pnProcInfo:UINT;rgAffectedApps:array of RM_PROCESS_INFO;var lpdwRebootReasons:DWORD):DWORD;
external 'RmGetList@Rstrtmgr.dll stdcall delayload';

function RmShutdown(dwSessionHandle:DWORD;lActionFlags:ULONG;fnStatus:RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK):DWORD;
external 'RmShutdown@Rstrtmgr.dll stdcall delayload';

function RmRestart(dwSessionHandle:DWORD;dwRestartFlags:DWORD;fnStatus:RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK):DWORD;
external 'RmRestart@Rstrtmgr.dll stdcall delayload';


var

  Processes: ProcessList;
  RestartManagerHandle:DWORD;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

{ Returns a list of running processes that currectly use one of the specified modules. }
{ Each module has to be a full path and filename to a DLL. }
function FindProcessesUsingModules(Modules:TArrayOfString;var Processes:ProcessList):DWORD;
var
    Handle:DWORD;
    Name:SessionKey;
    Apps:array of RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS;
    Services:TArrayOfString;
    Path:String;
    PathLength:DWORD;
    Needed,Have,i:UINT;
    AppList:array of RM_PROCESS_INFO;
    RebootReason:DWORD;
    Success:DWORD;
begin
    SetArrayLength(Processes,0);
    Result:=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    { NULL-terminate the array of chars. }
    Name[CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY+1]:=#0;
    if RmStartSession(Handle,0,Name)<>ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
        Exit;
    end;

    if RmRegisterResources(Handle,GetArrayLength(Modules),Modules,0,Apps,0,Services)=ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
        { Reallocate the arrays until they are large enough to hold the process information. }
        Needed:=1;
        repeat
            Have:=Needed;
            SetArrayLength(AppList,Have);
            Success:=RmGetList(Handle,Needed,Have,AppList,RebootReason);
        until (Success<>ERROR_MORE_DATA) or (Have>=Needed);

        if (Success=ERROR_SUCCESS) and (Needed>0) then begin
            for i:=0 to Needed-1 do begin
                { append to end of list }
                Have:=GetArrayLength(Processes);
                SetArrayLength(Processes,Have+1);
                { assign values to new entry }
                Processes[Have].ID:=AppList[i].Process.dwProcessId;
                Processes[Have].Name:=ArrayToString(AppList[i].strAppName);
                Processes[Have].Restartable:=AppList[i].bRestartable;
                Processes[Have].ToTerminate:=True;
            end;
            Result:=Handle;
        end;
    end;

    if (Result=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
      RmEndSession(Handle);

end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{ Returns a list of running processes that currectly use the specified module. 
{ The module has to be a full path and filename to a DLL.  This starts the }
{ RestartManager and returns its handle or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if failed  }
{ or nothing has lock }
function FindProcessesUsingModule(Module:String;var Processes:ProcessList):DWORD;
var
    Modules:TArrayOfString;
begin
    SetArrayLength(Modules,1);
    Modules[0]:=Module;
    Result:=FindProcessesUsingModules(Modules,Processes);
end;


{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

var
  UninstallDelDataPage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallConfirmPage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallProcessListPage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallBackButton: TNewButton;
  UninstallNextButton: TNewButton;

  UninstallAutoCloseRB: TNewRadioButton;

  DeleteAppDataCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;
  AppData: String;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure UpdateUninstallWizard;
begin
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallDelDataPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'Select Data Uninstall Options';
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := 'What data, if any, should be deleted?';
  end
    else
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallConfirmPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'Confirm Uninstall';
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := 'Confirm the uninstall options below.';
  end
    else
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallProcessListPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'Preparing to Uninstall';
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := 'Uninstall is preparing to uninstall {#MyAppName} from your computer.'
  end;

  UninstallBackButton.Visible :=
    (UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallConfirmPage) or 
    ((UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallDelDataPage) and (UninstallProcessListPage<>nil));

  if (UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallDelDataPage) or 
      ((UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallProcessListPage) and (UninstallDelDataPage<>nil)) then
  begin
    UninstallNextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
    UninstallNextButton.ModalResult := mrNone;
  end
    else
  begin
    UninstallNextButton.Caption := 'Uninstall';
    { Make the "Uninstall" button break the ShowModal loop }
    UninstallNextButton.ModalResult := mrOK;
  end;
end;  


{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure CreateUninstallConfirmPage();
var
  PageText: TNewStaticText;
begin

   { Create the second page }

    if (UninstallConfirmPage<>nil) then UninstallConfirmPage.Free();
    UninstallConfirmPage := TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallConfirmPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallConfirmPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallConfirmPage.Align := alClient;

    PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    PageText.Parent := UninstallConfirmPage;
    PageText.Top := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Top;
    PageText.Left := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Left;
    PageText.Width := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Width;
    PageText.Height := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Height;
    PageText.AutoSize := True;
    PageText.Wordwrap := True;
    PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
    PageText.Font.Size := 9;
    PageText.Caption := 'Click Uninstall to continue with removal of {#MyAppName}.';

    if DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Checked then
      PageText.Caption := PageText.Caption + #13#10#10 + 'WARNING: Application data will be deleted.';


end;


{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure UninstallNextButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallConfirmPage then
  begin
    UninstallNextButton.Visible := False;
    UninstallBackButton.Visible := False;
  end
  else 
  begin
    if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallDelDataPage then
    begin
      CreateUninstallConfirmPage();
      UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallConfirmPage;
    end
    else if UninstallDelDataPage<>nil then
    begin
      UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallDelDataPage;
    end
    else
    begin
      UninstallNextButton.Visible := False;
      UninstallBackButton.Visible := False;
    end;
    UpdateUninstallWizard;
  end;
end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure UninstallBackButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallConfirmPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallDelDataPage;
  end
  else if (UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallDelDataPage) and (UninstallProcessListPage<>Nil) then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallProcessListPage;
  end;
  UpdateUninstallWizard;
end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
var
  PageText: TNewStaticText;
  PageNameLabel: string;
  PageDescriptionLabel: string;
  CancelButtonEnabled: Boolean;
  CancelButtonModalResult: Integer;
  appinstalled: Boolean;
  top : Integer;
  ListBox : TNewListBox;
  i:Integer;
  UninstallNoCloseRB : TNewRadioButton;
begin

  RestartManagerHandle:=FindProcessesUsingModule(ExpandConstant('{app}\MyModule.dll'), Processes);


  if not UninstallSilent then
  begin

    { save labels / description }
    PageNameLabel := UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption;
    PageDescriptionLabel := UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;

    if RestartManagerHandle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      UninstallProcessListPage:=TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
      UninstallProcessListPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
      UninstallProcessListPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
      UninstallProcessListPage.Align := alClient;

      PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
      PageText.Parent := UninstallProcessListPage;
      PageText.Top := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Top;
      PageText.Left := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Left;
      PageText.Width := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Width;
      PageText.Height := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Height;
      PageText.AutoSize := True;
      PageText.WordWrap := True;
      PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
      PageText.Caption := 'The following applications are using files that need to be removed by the uninstaller.  It is recommended that you allow Uninstall to automatically close these applications.  After uninstall has completed, it will attempt to restart the applications.';

      ListBox := TNewListBox.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
      ListBox.Parent := UninstallProcessListPage;
      ListBox.Top := PageText.Top + PageText.Height + 16;
      ListBox.Left := PageText.Left;
      ListBox.Width := PageText.Width;
      ListBox.Height := ScaleY(97);
      ListBox.TabStop:=False;

      for i:=0 to GetArraylength(Processes)-1 do
      begin
        ListBox.Items.Add(Processes[i].Name);
      end;
      ListBox.ItemIndex:=-1;

      UninstallAutoCloseRB := TNewRadioButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
      UninstallAutoCloseRB .Parent := UninstallProcessListPage;
      UninstallAutoCloseRB .Checked := True;
      UninstallAutoCloseRB .Top := ListBox.Top+ListBox.Height+8;
      UninstallAutoCloseRB .Left := ListBox.Left;
      UninstallAutoCloseRB .Width := ListBox.Width;
      UninstallAutoCloseRB.Font.Size := 9;
      UninstallAutoCloseRB.Caption := '&Automatically close the applications';

      UninstallNoCloseRB := TNewRadioButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Parent := UninstallProcessListPage;
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Checked := False;
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Top := UninstallAutoCloseRB.Top+UninstallAutoCloseRB.Height+8;
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Left := UninstallAutoCloseRB.Left;
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Width := UninstallAutoCloseRB.Width;
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Font.Size := 9;
      UninstallNoCloseRB .Caption := '&Do not close the applications';



      { make page active }
      UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallProcessListPage;
    end;

    { work around elevated uninstaller for single user}
    AppData:=GetEnv('AppData');
    Log('AppData reported as' + AppData);

    if AppData<>'' then 
    begin
      appinstalled:=FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}/myapp.exe'));

      if appinstalled then
      begin

        { Create the first page and make it active }
        UninstallDelDataPage := TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
        UninstallDelDataPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
        UninstallDelDataPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
        UninstallDelDataPage.Align := alClient;

        PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
        PageText.Parent := UninstallDelDataPage;
        PageText.Top := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Top;
        PageText.Left := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Left;
        PageText.Width := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Width;
        PageText.Height := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Height;
        PageText.AutoSize := True;
        PageText.WordWrap := True;
        PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
        PageText.Caption := 'You have the option to delete the data assoicated with App Name';
        
        top:=PageText.Top + PageText.Height + 16;
        if appinstalled then
        begin 
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Parent := UninstallDelDataPage;
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Checked := False;
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Top := top;
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Left := PageText.Left+10;
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Width := PageText.Width - 10;
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Font.Size := 9;
          DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Caption := 'Delete all App Data';

          top:=DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Top + DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Height + 8;
        end;

        { set as first page if not already set }
        if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage=UninstallProgressForm.InstallingPage then
          UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage:=UninstallDelDataPage;


        { next button }
        UninstallNextButton := TNewButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
        UninstallNextButton.Parent := UninstallProgressForm;
        UninstallNextButton.Left := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Left - UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width - ScaleX(10);
        UninstallNextButton.Top := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Top;
        UninstallNextButton.Width := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width;
        UninstallNextButton.Height := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Height;
        UninstallNextButton.OnClick := @UninstallNextButtonClick;

        { back button }
        UninstallBackButton := TNewButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
        UninstallBackButton.Parent := UninstallProgressForm;
        UninstallBackButton.Left := UninstallNextButton.Left - UninstallNextButton.Width - ScaleX(10);
        UninstallBackButton.Top := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Top;
        UninstallBackButton.Width := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width;
        UninstallBackButton.Height := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Height;
        UninstallBackButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonBack);
        UninstallBackButton.OnClick := @UninstallBackButtonClick;

        { setup tab order }
        UninstallBackButton.TabOrder := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.TabOrder;
        UninstallNextButton.TabOrder := UninstallBackButton.TabOrder + 1;
        UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.TabOrder := UninstallNextButton.TabOrder + 1;

        { Run our wizard pages } 
        UpdateUninstallWizard;
        CancelButtonEnabled := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled
        UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True;

        { save value }
        CancelButtonModalResult := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult;

        { set value to use }
        UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;

        if UninstallProgressForm.ShowModal = mrCancel then 
        begin
          if RestartManagerHandle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
          begin
            RmEndSession(RestartManagerHandle);
            RestartManagerHandle:=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
          end;
          Abort;
        end;

        { Restore the standard page payout }
        UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled := CancelButtonEnabled;
        UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult := CancelButtonModalResult;

        UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := PageNameLabel;
        UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := PageDescriptionLabel;

        UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallProgressForm.InstallingPage;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function IsDeleteAppData: Boolean;
begin
  Result:=(DeleteAppDataCheckBox<>nil) and DeleteAppDataCheckBox.Checked;
end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}


procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  Res : Boolean;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
      if (RestartManagerHandle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) and (UninstallAutoCloseRB<>nil) and (UninstallAutoCloseRB.Checked) then
        RmShutdown(RestartManagerHandle, 0, 0);
  end
  else if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    if IsDeleteAppData then
    begin
      Res:=DelTree(AppData+'\MyAppDataDir', true, true, true);
      Log('Delete '+AppData+'\MyAppDataDir result: '+IntToStr(Integer(Res)));
    end;

    if (RestartManagerHandle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) and (UninstallAutoCloseRB<>nil) and (UninstallAutoCloseRB.Checked) then
      RmRestart(RestartManagerHandle, 0, 0);

    if (RestartManagerHandle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    begin
      RmEndSession(RestartManagerHandle);
      RestartManagerHandle:=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    end;
  end;
end;
```