# How to schedule task with gui programmatically

Tags: cmd, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

(I'm working under Windows XP)

A simplification of the approach I'm taking (which isn't working) is as follows:

```
C:\>schtasks /create /tn "MyTask" /tr "mspaint" /sc daily /st 11:43:00 /ru "System"
```

I know the task is being scheduled because you can view it in task scheduler.

I know it runs and does not stop because you can view that in task scheduler.

However: The Paint program never becomes visible. (Is it running as another user maybe?)

How do I schedule a task with a GUI so that it becomes visible when the task runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the user in whose context the task should be run and check the "Run only when logged in" checkbox. AFAIK this can only be done in the GUI, not via `schtasks`.

Comment: I need to run via `schtasks` http://stackoverflow.com/a/38757852/285594 because i have a GUI Kiosk, where i need to kill the GUI via schedule task, how to do that?

Comment: Can you please show how to run a schtasks for username "iamzero" who is running some kiosk application, now schtasks need to kill that app

Comment: @YumYumYum Dude, you have more than 6k rep. Do I really need to explain to you how to ask a question on SO?

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the Tasks with simple "`schtasks`" command. 
For idea, i think the best way to write a hybrid software, what can handle the Task Interface 2.0 and the schtasks command via process/commandline.

You also can watch the schtasks command line response in the background.

For full schtasks list are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)