# Process.Kill() Access Denied

Tags: c#, .net, process, kill

When I run the following code, a  Win32Exception is thrown for Access Denied.  I cannot find any solutions via search. How do I fix this?

```
foreach (ListViewItem list in showprocesses.SelectedItems)
{
    Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(list.Tag));
    if (p != null)
        p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Well what process is it trying to kill?

Comment: You get exception for all the processes you try or some specific process?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Any process http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/a7/1c/gg/1no2yr.jpg

Comment: I found another reason; I was attempting to kill a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process.  I was creating an Excel automation object from a web application running under IIS with setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" true.  This means IIS is running 32-bit.  The installed version of Excel was 64-bit.  Creating / using the Excel object was fine, but I was unable to shut it down via Process.Kill (which shouldn't be necessary, but that's another problem).

Answer (score 17):

You will generally get this error if you do not have the necessary permissions.  You must be an administrator, and in win vista and above, run your app/process in elevated mode.  Furthermore, there are certain processes that even as admin you won't be able to kill, some deemed system critical, etc, and you may need to run as **system**, and then there are those that even system can't kill, like antivirus, or an actual virus, because they don't want you killing their process

Another possibility is that if the process is already terminating, it will also throw that exception, see [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20170724173918/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)

Comment: My application is run in Admin mode.
And I try to kill processes like Spotify etc.

Comment: have you tried killing it outside of your app?  try downloading pskill, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx, and see if you can kill it using that app, if you can, then there is something wrong with your app (not runing in elevated mode?  you got the wrong process in `p`?), remember to run the **cmd promp in elevated mode** then invoke pskill from that elevated cmd prompt

Comment: I tried to kill spotify with this code:
'//foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("spotify"))
            //{
            //    proc.Kill();
            //}'
And it worked just fine.

Seems as my original code doesn't work. I'll have to take a look at that one then. Now I can at least rule Admin right problems.

Comment: try
            {
                int procID = System.Convert.ToInt32(showprocesses.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text);
                Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(procID);
                tempProc.Kill();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not kill process", "Error");
            }

It seems like tinkering with my code fixed it.
This killed the selected process without any issue :)

Answer (score 4):

I had this kind of problems with a Delphi application Under Windows 8.1
My application was closing, but was still in the background processes of the task manager.
Impossible to kill it with TaskKill (tried admin mode, "/F" option, from command line...)
Finally I found out that Windows "marked" a DLL of my application as "IgnoreFreeLibrary".
That is why my application was not closing.
Here is an extract of the registry :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"{MyApplicationPathAndExeName}"="$ IgnoreFreeLibrary<DllWithProblemName.Dll>"
```

I erased the registry entry and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and used these codes to solve the problem:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string ClassName, string WindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int HWND = FindWindow(null, "My Window");//window title

        SendMessage(HWND, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
    }
```

Comment: is your answer related to this question?

Comment: sure! p.Kill(); gives you an win32Exception, so u need to use user32.dll to close the windows of other programs or assemblies.

Comment: I think it should be SendMessage first parameter IntPtr not int

Answer (score 1):

Here's the guts of my `ForceKill`. It starts by trying to `.Kill()` the process. Then attempts to kill the process via `taskkill`, then attempts to kill the process via `wmic`.

```
    public static void ForceKill(Process proc)
    {

        // Accessing ProcessName could throw an exception if the process has already been killed.
        string processName = string.Empty;
        try { processName = proc.ProcessName; } catch (Exception ex) { }

        // ProcessId can be accessed after the process has been killed but we'll do this safely anyways.
        int pId = 0;
        try { pId = proc.Id; } catch (Exception ex) { }

        // Will only work if started by this instance of the dll.
        try { proc.Kill(); } catch (Exception ex) { }

        // Fallback to task kill
        if (pId > 0)
        {
            var taskKilPsi = new ProcessStartInfo("taskkill");
            taskKilPsi.Arguments = $"/pid {proc.Id} /T /F";
            taskKilPsi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            taskKilPsi.UseShellExecute = false;
            taskKilPsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            taskKilPsi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            taskKilPsi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            var taskKillProc = Process.Start(taskKilPsi);
            taskKillProc.WaitForExit();
            String taskKillOutput = taskKillProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // Contains success
            String taskKillErrorOutput = taskKillProc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Fallback to wmic delete process.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(processName))
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757852/591285
            var wmicPsi = new ProcessStartInfo("wmic");
            wmicPsi.Arguments = $@"process where ""name='{processName}.exe'"" delete";
            wmicPsi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            wmicPsi.UseShellExecute = false;
            wmicPsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            wmicPsi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            wmicPsi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            var wmicProc = Process.Start(wmicPsi);
            wmicProc.WaitForExit();
            String wmicOutput = wmicProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // Contains success
            String wmicErrorOutput = wmicProc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

You could check if `proc.Kill()` was successful or `taskKillOutput` or `wmicOutput` for `success` instead of hammering all three methods every time.

I find `proc.Kill()` will fail on process started by administrators, but `taskkill` and `wmic` seem to work fine as long as it's not some kind of protected system process.

Answer (score -3):

try { pyProcess.Kill(); } 
catch (Exception error)  { Console.WriteLine(error.ToString()); }

No need for Admin Access. But this will work only some process only.

Answer (score -4):

disable UAC on windows solve the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Never actually do this. This is horrible advice.