# Windows 10 - Taskkill never kills a task

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskkill

I have a application which is a keyboard on the screen, I need to kill it via taskkill but it is impossible to kill.
How do you kill it?

[image]

I tried all combinations but it won't just get killed?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taskkill /f doesnt kill a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528963/taskkill-f-doesnt-kill-a-process)

Comment: Use `tasklist /v` to see what you need to put.

Comment: The error message says that it couldn't find the correct process to terminate, you'll need to somehow improve the search criteria.  Or, could be a privileges issue.  Are you running the script as elevated?

Comment: Following Answer only worked, all the rest does not work at all.

Comment: How to to run `wmic process where name='TouchIt.exe' delete` from scheduler? when i am running this from scheduler then it fails, but when i manually run this then only works. Does anyone know how you can run this from scheduler and be sure it does exactly like it was manually applied?

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to copy and paste the from the cmd prompt then posting an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to kill the process using wmic using hte following command.

```
C:\>wmic process where name='TouchIt.exe' delete
```

Comment: Why didn't you try `TASKKILL` with the image name option?

Comment: TASKKILL never ever worked for such long name of task