# Python selenium webdriver.quit() can not kill chromedriver.exe process

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller, windows-server-2016

I have used python Selenium to wrote a web scraper to download files auto. when I ran it on my local PC, it worked well. but when I run it on my VM on Azure. The method webdriver.quit() can not kill chromedriver.exe process and this zombie process keeps my CPU and memory usage very high.

I have referred to [release Selenium chromedriver.exe from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory) and what I have tried following is all failed to kill it:

1. end the process in the task manager (Access denied)
2. use taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f in admin mode CMD(can not be terminated)
3. use kill -id pid in powershell admin mode(can not be terminated)

I have given the full control permission to the windows user to the chromedriver.exe and here is some detail about the environment.

- OS:windows server 2016 Datacenter(VM on Azure)
- Browser:Chrome
- Browser version:87.0.4280.141
- Browser Driver version:87.0.4280.88.0
- Language Bindings version:Python 3.7.9
- Selenium version:3.141.0

what I can do to kill this process, for now, is only reboot my VM. Can anyone help me?
No same issue happened on my local PC(Windows 10),So is this something about the OS or system setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Taskkill /f doesn't kill a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528963/taskkill-f-doesnt-kill-a-process)