# How do I kill/remove the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, localhost, kill

I do not have admin permissions on my computer. I am trying to kill the processes of a localhost port.

I have tried `netstat -ano | findstr :6543` and `taskkill /PID 6360 /F` and it said `ERROR: The process with PID 6360 could not be terminated. Reason: Access is denied.`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528963/taskkill-f-doesnt-kill-a-process) help in any way?

Comment: no it still does not work