# Most ungraceful way to terminate a process (that's being terminated)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

What is the most ungraceful way to really terminate a process?

I was trying to use **Process.Kill** (System.Diagnostics), but it has a drawback that renders it useless for me:

> If the call to the Kill method is made while the process is currently terminating, a Win32Exception is thrown for Access Denied.

I'm in fact dealing with an application (which isn't mine) that crashes frequently and even gets stuck in the termination process in a manner that only rebooting would help.

Running **TASKKILL /F /IM ...** also exits with "Access denied". I also tried to P/Invoke **TerminateProcess()**.

Although this question might be oddly specific, I'd be very thankful for an answer.

Comment: If it's already being terminated, what makes you think telling it to terminate again will help?

Comment: You could try killing off its individual threads.  P/Invoke probably required.

Comment: Process.Kill should work. Are you really trying to stop a service? What app are you trying to kill.

Comment: A terminating process can only get stuck in kernel mode, e.g. if there is any pending I/O outstanding. As soon as the process is marked for termination, nothing more can be done about it without endangering the integrity of kernel state. Use process explorer and/or a kernel debugger to try to find out where exactly does the problematic application get stuck in kernel mode. If nothing helps, put the problematic application inside a virtual machine and turn it off.

Comment: You've already used all available weapons in the arsenal.  Only rebooting the machine is more ungraceful.

Comment: @AndrewBarber You didn't get my point. I didn't want to just _tell it_ to terminate, I was hoping there was a way to make Windows _force it to terminate_.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy A virtual machine! That's an excellent idea! Thanks!

Comment: I do feel your pain there, and I understand what you mean. Unfortunately, `Process.Kill()` and `TerminateProcess()` are your only options, aside from what Hans and Anton have noted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after asking this question I figured out why the application would hang in a fashion that only a reboot would help ([many thanks to this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988/really-killing-a-process-in-windows/50011#50011)): **Avast Anti-Virus**. Once I removed that software from all workstations the 3rd party application still crashes, but it gets actually terminated after doing so and thus can be run again.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
private void Test(){
    KillProcess("notepad");
}

private void KillProcess(string processName) {
    Process[] appProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

    if(appProcesses.Length == 0)
        return;

    // Kill and wait for app to exit
    appProcesses[0].Kill();
    appProcesses[0].WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for every application except the one I'm actually trying to terminate!